# Ant build.xml file unable to use a property in the fileset element

Tags: java, ant, path, build.xml

I am using an ant build.xml to build my simple war file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<project name="cellar" default="war">

  <target name="init">
    <property file="${user.home}/build.properties"/>
    <property name="app.name" value="${ant.project.name}"/>
    <property name="src.dir" location="src"/>
    <property name="lib.dir" location="lib"/>
    <property name="build.dir" location="build"/>
    <property name="dist.dir" location="dist"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" location="${build.dir}/classes"/>

    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>

  <path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="lib">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <target name="compile" depends="init" >
    <javac destdir="${classes.dir}" debug="true" srcdir="${src.dir}">
      <classpath refid="classpath"/>
    </javac>
  </target>

  <target name="war" depends="compile" >
    <war destfile="${dist.dir}/${app.name}.war" webxml="${src.dir}/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}/main/webapp/"/>
        <lib dir="${lib.dir}"/>
        <classes dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    </war>
  </target>

  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
  </target>

</project>
```

The ant build.xml shown above works perfectly. However in the path tag if I replace the dir="lib" with  dir="${lib.dir}" (within the fileset tags) then the build fails and I get an error like that shown below

BUILD FAILED
c:\Java\code\Cellar\build.xml:22: c:\Java\code\Cellar\${lib.dir} does not exist.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Why do you define `<property file="${user.home}/build.properties"/>` and adding more properties inline, try to remove the property include and try again

Comment: I would try to replace `<property name="lib.dir" location="lib"/>` with: `<property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>`. Would that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classpath is defined when the build file is loaded, whereas the properties are only defined when the init target is executed.

Move the properties definition outside of the `init` target, or move the fileset definition in a target executed after `init` is executed.

Comment: Thanks. Moved the properties outside and it worked like a charm.